# What is the Initial size of newly created database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

What is the Initial size of newly created database in SQL Server before specifing size for mdf/ldf?

Answer (score 1):

The file sizes as well as other properties of the [soon to be created] database are **set to the values of the corresponding properties of the model database**.

The database isn't created however until one supplies the path and name (and possibly alter the initial size) of the MDF and LDF files.